# Custom devise method : render 'new' redirect to /users instead of /users/sign_up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, render

I have a custom protected method in my devise `registration_controller.rb` :

```
 before_action :check_secret_code, only: [:create]
  # Method de condition pour création du compte
  include ApplicationHelper
  # need application_helper.rb or will not work.

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    super
  end

  # POST /resource
  def create
    super
  end 

def check_secret_code
   if Invitation.where(:invit_name => params[:user]["invit_ref"]).blank?
      render 'new'
   else
      Invitation.where(:invit_name => params[:user]["invit_ref"]).destroy_all
      return true
   end
end
```

But when the `render 'new'` is used, it's render `/users` instead of `/users/sign_up` with no persistant infos. Do you know why ?

Here is my application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @user ||= User.new
  end
  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
end
```

Comment: How do you end up at this route? e.g. What view contains the form that is submitted here and what does the controller action look like? It seems like you want the data to show on `new` and it looks like you have a `User` in the new action so in order for that data to persist you would also need the `@user` instance variable in this method. But without the additional context it is difficult to tell

Comment: Hey @engineersmnky thanks for your answer ! My route for this devise form is devise `users/sign_up` associated with `registrations/new.html.erb`. I have no routes ending at `/users`. This is what is weird as it is kind of creating a route out of nowhere. I edited my question with more infos ;)

Comment: facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

`render 'new'` renders `new` template, but url and action stay the same.

For example, you call `render 'new'` from `create` method:

```
def create
  @model = Model.new(params[:model])
  if @model.valid?
    @model.save!
    redirect_to :some_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

if `@model` is not valid, it renders `new` template with `@model` variable from `create` method.

Thus, in your case, if you want the user to be redirected to `users/sign_up` you need to explicitly redirect him to this page:

Either by `redirect_to 'users/sign_up'` or by using a path helper method.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Igor! But with a redirect_to, will I not lose the benefit of alerts and auto-completion when the form will be rendered for the second time?